# convert data set to XMLdocument

Tags: c#

i have function in a console application to generate excel file through C#.net 
there is one prameter is a xmldocument 
 this is the function

```
static void GenerateExcel( String xlsFileName   , XmlDocument XMLFILE   , String FILE_NAME)
{
    ..
}
```

and i will call this function to another function

```
MpDs = objDAL.ExecuteDataset(BLL_ConnString.getConnString(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "USP_EDI_HAPPYCHIC_COMMON_LOG", custom);
        if (MpDs.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = MpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FILENAME"].ToString();
            GenerateExcel("Xsl_EDI_HC_GenerateExcel.xsl",document.LoadXml(MpDs) ,filename);
        }
```

i want convert  dataset to xmldocument 
i got error

can u pls anybody can help me

tanx in advance

Nisha

Comment: Check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.LoadXml(MpDs.GetXml());
```