# How to deserialize xml string to datatable using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Please suggest me any solution to deserialize following xml string to datatable using c#. I didn't any related solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<seatMap>
  <errorCode>0</errorCode>
    <xml>
      <Seat-Map> 
        <Lower-Deck>
          <column id="1"> 
            <row id="1"><seat number="1C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="2"><seat number="2C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="3"><seat number="3C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="4"><seat number="4C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="5"><seat number="5C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="6"><seat number="6C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="7"><seat number="7C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="8"><seat number="8C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="9"><seat number="9C" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="10"><seat number="10C" status="0" /> </row> 
          </column>
          <column id="2"> 
            <row id="1"><seat number="1B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="2"><seat number="2B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="3"><seat number="3B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="4"><seat number="4B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="5"><seat number="5B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="6"><seat number="6B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="7"><seat number="7B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="8"><seat number="8B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="9"><seat number="9B" status="0" /> </row> 
            <row id="10"><seat number="10B" status="0" /> </row> 
          </column>
          <column id="3"> 
            <row id="1"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="2"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="3"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="4"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="5"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="6"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="7"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="8"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="9"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
            <row id="10"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
          </column>
          <column id="4"> 
             <row id="1"><seat number="1A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="2"><seat number="2A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="3"><seat number="3A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="4"><seat number="4A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="5"><seat number="5A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="6"><seat number="6A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="7"><seat number="7A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="8"><seat number="8A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="9"><seat number="9A" status="0" /> </row> 
             <row id="10"><seat number="10A" status="0" /> </row> 
          </column> 
        </Lower-Deck>
      </Seat-Map> 
    </xml>
  </seatMap>
```

**But I need following DataTable from that XML String :**

```
public static DataTable querySeat(string bus_id)
    {
        // Query the Seat Layout of the Trip
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc;
        dc = new DataColumn("column", Type.GetType("System.Int32")); // Column No. of the seat
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dc = new DataColumn("row", Type.GetType("System.Int32")); // Row N. of the seat
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add("seat"); // Seat Label
        dc = new DataColumn("deck", Type.GetType("System.Int32")); // Deck, 1 = Lower Deck, 2 = Upper Deck
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add("status"); // Status, 1 = Available, 0 = Taken
        return dt;
    }
```

**DataTable Output :**

```
Coulmn        |      Row      |       Seat     |      Deck     |   Status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    1                 1c               1           0
1                    2                 2c               1           0
1                    3                 3c               1           0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following Code

```
public static DataTable querySeat(string id)
{
    string xmlStr = "";           //Place Your XML String here

    DataTable result = new DataTable("SeatData");

    DataColumn columnColumn = result.Columns.Add("column", typeof(Int32));
    DataColumn rowColumn = result.Columns.Add("row", typeof(Int32));
    DataColumn seatColumn = result.Columns.Add("seat", typeof(String));
    DataColumn deckColumn = result.Columns.Add("deck", typeof(Int32));
    DataColumn statusColumn = result.Columns.Add("status", typeof(Int32));

    XElement.Parse(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xmlStr)).Descendants("seat").ToList().ForEach(
       (element) =>
          {
              DataRow row = result.NewRow();
              row.SetField<int>(columnColumn, Convert.ToInt32(element.Parent.Parent.Attribute("id").Value));
              row.SetField<int>(rowColumn, Convert.ToInt32(element.Parent.Attribute("id").Value));
              row.SetField<string>(seatColumn, element.Attribute("number").Value);
              int deckNo = -1;
              if (element.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name.LocalName == "Lower-Deck")
                 deckNo = 1;
              row.SetField<int>(deckColumn, deckNo);
              string statusString = element.Attribute("status").Value;
              int statusValue = -1;
              if (statusString == "blank")
                  statusValue = 1;
              else if (statusString == "0")
                  statusValue = 0;
              row.SetField<int>(statusColumn, statusValue);
              result.Rows.Add(row);
          }
       );
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ReadXml method of the DataTable object.

Comment: When I am using ReadXml method I am getting following output        `code` errorCode     |      xml                                           ------------------------------------------------------------------ 0                    | <Seat-Map><Lower-Deck>........</Seat-Map>

Comment: You will probably have to spend some time working on the xml to get it right. Are you closing the lower-deck tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a DataSet to XML and back using the WriteXML and ReadXML methods of the Dataset.
(check, for example, [Convert Dataset to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml))

This is only possible if you also create the XML yourself from the application.