# Sort datagridviewcolumn as datetime rather than as string

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I retrieve data from a sql server, where some columns are datetime, integer and strings. As I load the datatable and bind it to the datasource of the datagridview, the latter sorts every column as if it was a string, eg:

```
1
10
100
2
20
200
```

Same happens with datetime.

How can I make the datatable (or datagridview) realize it's an integer or datetime and sort it correctly?

Thanks

edit:

this is how I load the data

```
dgEquipos.DataSource = new WebRequester().EquiposTotalesActivos();
```

EquiposTotalesActivos is:

```
var xml = new Request("EquiposTotalesPorEmpresa").AddHeader("usuario", User.UserId.ToString()).MakeRequest();
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XmlReader reader = xdoc.CreateReader();
dataset.ReadXml(reader);
return dataset.Tables[0];
```

And the webservice makes the query and returns the xml

```
retorno = new DataSet();
var d = new SqlDataAdapter(_command);
return d.Fill(retorno).GetXml();
```

edit2:

this is what I should have used. [Convert Dataset to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml?rq=1)

however making this change in the webservice broke most of my software, so it's not viable. How can I locally set the data type of the column in order to make it sort as datetime and not as string?

Comment: _" bind it to the datasource of the datagridview"_ which is a `BindingSource`? How do you fill the `DataTable`, do the columns have the correct type?

Comment: edited the main post

Comment: i don't set the columns type anywhere, however the SQL obviously has assigned the correct data type (datetime, integer, etc)

Comment: AFAIK you loose this kind of information when you execute `GetXml` as this will convert everything to string. Can you show the XML generated by that method?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NRKd1v6f

Comment: ...and there you have the answer: No type information in there.

Comment: I see. But how can I either set the datatype in the XML or assign the datatype in the datatable? I tried cloning the datatable and assigning datatypes before importing rows but didn't work either.