# How to write data from an excel to an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I would like to develop a program that has to read excel files and write to an xml file but I'm not sure how I can write the data to the xml file.

I'm reading the excel file like this:

```
var fileName = @"C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\test.xlsx";
var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;

var conexao = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);

var sql = "SELECT * FROM [PARAC1$]";

var cmm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conexao);
var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

conexao.Open();

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dr = cmm.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(dr);

conexao.Close();
```

and I'm writing the xml file like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
doc.AppendChild(docNode);

XmlNode ejournal = doc.CreateElement("EJournal");
doc.AppendChild(ejournal);

XmlNode dealer = doc.CreateElement("Dealer");
XmlAttribute valueID = doc.CreateAttribute("ID");
valueID.Value = dealerID;
dealer.Attributes.Append(valueID);
ejournal.AppendChild(dealer);

XmlNode PeriodBegin = doc.CreateElement("PeriodBegin");
PeriodBegin.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(data));
dealer.AppendChild(PeriodBegin);

XmlNode PeriodEnd = doc.CreateElement("PeriodEnd");
PeriodEnd.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(data));
dealer.AppendChild(PeriodEnd);

XmlNode Transaction = doc.CreateElement("Transaction");
dealer.AppendChild(Transaction);



XmlNode CardNumber = doc.CreateElement("CardNumber");
CardNumber.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("7710007007379"));
Transaction.AppendChild(CardNumber);
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\pedro1123.xml");
```

Comment: Why are you using sql. Why not Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: This was the way I found

Comment: well, I experienced problems with culture using Interop, had to change to en-US everytime and then back to pt-PT and was hell with culture specific formats... (just a side note as Pedro sounds like a non EN name)

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel will be far easier I imagine.

Comment: @rmjoia I am portuguese

Comment: @Pedro - It is a fair approach, Don't switch to Office Interop, that will create more problems than it solves. If you don't want to use a Jet/SQL connection then use a native approach such as the ClosedXml or EPPlus packages.

Comment: @Pedro I suspeted that, me too :) Interop is easy, but you may find the same issues I did.. still I don't know what changed since the last time I used, I would give it a try.. just the workarounds for dates and times were very messy... having the month and the day switching when it was possible to parse the day as a month.. which caused issues in reports

Comment: Isn't this far easier? https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Loading-and-Modifying-Files

Comment: What is the best way to transfer data to an xml file, I was thinking of passing the excel data to a database in sql and then using a sqlreader to read the data, is it a good solution?

Comment: Use Xml Serialization - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml However, to be honest, I feel you would be best served (in the long term) reading your data into objects and then serializing.

Comment: @Cal279 But how I can convert excel to sql database

Comment: @Pedro - not sure what you mean - do you need to insert into a SQL database?

Comment: @Cal279 I think is a better soluction