# save datagridview in file xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

i have issue with save the datagridview data in file xml but i have issue in below

```
private void WriteXml(string path)        {
            try
            {
                //BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = (DataSet)(dataGridView1.DataSource);
                
                ds.WriteXml(path, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR\r\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml

Comment: i used that ;but i have error:BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)(bs.DataSource);
            try
            {
                dt.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\ykama\OneDrive\Documents\Zoom\DataXml.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
                dt.Dispose();
                MessageBox.Show("OK");

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException) {
                MessageBox.Show("Erreur");
            }

Comment: What is wrong with current code?

Comment: display Message Erreur

Comment: @JohnG I get Erreuur MessageBox.Show("Erreur") because passed to catch exception and the DataSource of dataGridView1 is the result of sqlCommand requete sql

Comment: so simply i need export the data of dataGridView1 to file xml so i used the code in above but display Erreur coming from catch exception si if you have any idee thanks in advance

Comment: Erreur Message :::Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: same code i used

Comment: ds a été null. ..............

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("col2");

        DataRow rs = dt.NewRow();
        rs[0] = "test1";
        rs[1] = "test1";
        dt.Rows.Add(rs);

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.AcceptChanges();


        StreamWriter serialWriter;
        serialWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\1\test1.xml");
        XmlSerializer xmlWriter = new XmlSerializer(ds.GetType());
        xmlWriter.Serialize(serialWriter, ds);
        serialWriter.Close();
```